# Getting the error, too many aggregate queries 301

Tags: soql

I have a test class in sandbox and while clicking run test i am getting error message, too many aggregate soql queries 301. I tried to find this error on internet and salesforce documentation however either this is something new or nobody has got it yet.

Comment: The limit is new (301), but the limit itself has always existed in some form. Try posting some code.

Answer (score 0):

You are right there is nothing mentioned on manual and its new.

If its just test class issue then there is very simple way to address this.

You just split your test class in multiple classes. When you run complete test suite every class runs in its own context and so get separate SQOL limit. So with 2 classes you will be able to call aggregate 600 SOQL .

There is one more way, you can use start test stop test to increase limits in test class.

Answer (score 0):

Post your code and how many methods in your test class.

Try to use Start test and stop test so you can get fresh governor limits.
But you can only use once in a test method.

My idea is to try to create a separate methods and it is also best practice to do bulk testing always.. @Sara

Comment: Why do you have this as an answer? You should post it in the Question>Comments section.